# how to maximize the list to consume max space using css

Tags: html, css

[image: list]
this a list for menu purposes i want to maximize the space on the right to match the space on the left but when i increase padding or margin the last menu goes down that should i do for this to match the menu on the left here is my code

css:

```
    #headermenu {
    /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
}
#headermenu ul {

}
#headermenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    #headermenu ul li:hover > ul {
        display:inline-block;
    }
#headermenu ul {
    background: #f69b58; 
    /*background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);*/
    padding: 0 20.05px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
    #headermenu ul:after {
        content: ""; 
        clear: both; 
        display: block;
    }   

    #headermenu ul li {
        float: left;
    }
    #headermenu ul li:hover {
        background: #3eaee9;
        /*background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);*/
    }
        #headermenu ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    #headermenu ul li a {
        display: block; 
        padding: 15px 63.9px;
        color: #552f01; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }   
#headermenu ul ul {
    background: #f69b58; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
}
    #headermenu ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        /*border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;*/
        position: relative;
    }
        #headermenu ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 63.9px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            #headermenu ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #3eaee9;
            }   
    #headermenu ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; 
        left: 100%; 
        top:0;
    }
```

list:

```
<ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Town Office</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Business</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Residents</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Tourists</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

using this approach...
any help is appreciated...
what causes the extra space in the image in the black circle

[image: over]

Comment: same problem how you remove the space at the end of the list and why does it have that space

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways is to use a table-cell layout...no, not an actual table but...

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KhC94/4/)

**CSS**

```
#menu ul {
    padding: 0 3px;
    display: table;     /* add this */
    width:100%;     /* add this */
}
#menu-list li {
    height: 45px;
    //width: 180px;     /* remove this */
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f69b58;
    //float: left;     /* remove this */
    display:table-cell; /* add this */ 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
#menu-list li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}
#menu-list li:active {
    color:black;
    background-color: #3EAEE9;
}
#menu-list li:hover {
    background:#3eaee9;
}
#menu-list li.current {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(7, 80, 158), rgb(6, 101, 243));
    background-color: #3EAEE9;
}
```

Comment: is there a way i can maximize the space without using table cell i kinda need my approach to work..

Comment: Javascript can calculate these widths for you or you can just count the number of list items and set their width as a percentage of the total.

Comment: i tried using % but the problem is the last item goes down..and i wont work because i have another list when on hover and it affects that list as well when i change size to %

Comment: you mean to say the only way is to adjust the width nothing more?thank you for clearing this out mate i appreciate it happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You should change **#menu-list li** {display: inline-block;} **#menu ul** {text-align: center;}, delete `float: left` and change `width` of `li`

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dosandk/tLHW4/)

but I would advise use `display:table`, `display: table-cell` properties;

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dosandk/XMkr6/)

Comment: is there a way i can maximize the space without using table cell i kinda need my approach to work..

Comment: @Hak Hak I can offer solution with li {display: inline-block} and ul {
white-space: nowrap;} http://jsfiddle.net/dosandk/tLHW4/

Comment: its working really nice but i need to make it in float left because im planning to put another list on hover if i user your code when i hover the menu in the the next level is not looking really nice

Comment: @Hak Hak Can you share code with second level menu?