# Text/ Structure breaking when resize the browser

Tags: html, css

I have following structure: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/ZZa8j/)

[image]

HTML & CSS Code is as following:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="test"> Hello </li>  
    <li class="test"> Welcome </li>
    <li class="test"> Test Process </li>
    <li class="test"> Text Message </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{

    width: 100%;
}

.test{
    height:20px;
    width:20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

When I resize the browser the `<li>` tag widget structure is working fine (Not breaking) but the text inside the widget are breaking like:

[image]

My question is How can I make the text inside the widget adjustable so that It will not break.
**Is there any way to fix this using only CSS ?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not break"? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Try 'overflow: hidden;'

Comment: @Ronen: Not break means expand accordingly :)

Comment: maybe `@media screen` of CSS3 could help , check [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11777771/3419997)

Comment: You can use `table-cell layout` as described here  - [**Stack Overflow Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629444/how-to-maximize-the-list-to-consume-max-space-using-css)

Comment: use white-space:nowrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide

```
min-width:20%;
```

instead of

```
width:20%;
```

It should work..

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZZa8j/2/

Comment: +1 for the answer. Yes, This approach is working but My box structure is also change while resizing the browser i.e. the size of box,text containing Hello is become small comparing with the others so not consistance. :)

Comment: li only have 20% width of ul. As ul's width decreases width of li also decreases.If you provide fixed width (in px), i think this problem can avoid.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me check with this approach using pixels.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to expand accordingly, you can simply remove the explicit `height` and set a `min-height` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZa8j/8/).

If you want to clip the text and indicate the user that text is clipped, you can use the [text-oveflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZa8j/5/).

```
.test{
 white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
 /*other styles*/
}
```

If you actually want the content to expand as much as possible and scoll if not, you could use [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d)'s `table-cell` [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629620/2333214) like he mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are blocked by my proxy so I'm not sure if it's the answer that you need, but you can avoid break between 2 words with the css property white-space.

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

see fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZZa8j/4/

Answer (score 1):

add `min-width:450px;` to the `<ul>`.

check my <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZa8j/6/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
ul{
    min-width:450px;
    width: 100%;
}

.test{
    height:20px;
    width:20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="test"> Hello </li>
    <li class="test"> Welcome </li>
    <li class="test"> Test Process </li>
    <li class="test"> Text Message </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/ZZa8j/10/embedded/result/)

[Code Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/ZZa8j/10/)

Try :

```
overflow: hidden;
 min-width:100px;
```

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: Working with overflow: hidden but Not able to see the full text in this case.

Comment: Did you check the JSfiddle link?? whole text is visible

Comment: added jsfiddle screenshot for you

Comment: Yes,Checked.Can you please resize the browser 3 to 4 times. It will break.

Comment: In that case you need to set `min-width`

Comment: Yes. Can you check this fiddle with both 'overflow:hidden' & 'min-width:20%'. http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/ZZa8j/9/ . This approach is working but My box structure is also change while resizing the browser i.e. the size of box,text containing Hello is become small comparing with the others so not consistance. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57269/discussion-between-vaibhav-jain-and-nivedita).