# Justified horizontal list with minified HTML

Tags: html, css

For a horizontal menu i want to **justify the list items** over the full width.

This works:

CSS:

```
ul {height: 1em;text-align: justify;overflow: hidden;padding-left: 0;}
li {display: inline-block;}
li:last-child {padding-left: 100%;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>flexible number</li>
    <li>and length of</li>
    <li>list items</li>
    <li>hidden</li>
</ul>
```

OUTPUT (the lines are showing the width of the UL):

```
|flexible number             and length of              list items|
```

If i delete all whitespaces and linebreaks to **minify the HTML-output**, it doesn't work any more.

SMALLER HTML:

```
<ul><li>flexible number</li><li>and length of</li><li>list items</li><li>hidden</li></ul>
```

It looks like this:

```
|flexible numberand length oflist items                           |
```

Is there any chance to **get the "normal" behavior back** with pure CSS?

Please have a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tfranz/HpP99/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to maximize the list to consume max space using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629444/how-to-maximize-the-list-to-consume-max-space-using-css)

Comment: This duplicate shows a list with **another design**. I need a list of elements which looks like "text-align:justify".

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jsFiddle below - you should be able to use % widths and floats to do this without padding or margins.  Standard minification should not affect the results.

http://jsfiddle.net/MNally/CWjMz/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="the-list">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

ul#the-list {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;    
}

li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#c9c;
    width:33.333%;
}
```

I set the margin/padding to '0' to illustrate that they're not needed.  You can remove these lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need another design and behavior of the list. Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Tfranz/HpP99/

Answer (score 0):

How about using `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` ?

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HpP99/2/

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the same. Have a look at the last item: with "display:table" there is space after the last item, it is not like "text-align:justify" with **no space on the right side**.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact problem. HTML minification removes whitespaces as we all know, but in this case it breaks the CSS "text-align: justify" and "text-align-last: justify".

The solution is to implement a single line jQuery code to add white spaces back after the closing tags for the list items:

```
$('#the_list li').after("&#32;");
```

I hope someone finds this helpful.