# Make <li> elements expand to fill the parent container

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Welcome to the Information Management Hub</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
            <ul class="central-nav">
                <li><%= link_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path, :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path, :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path, :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path, :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg" %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my customized CSS beyond Bootstrap:

```
.central-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.central-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have tried numerous methods to have the list items expand to the width of the unordered list's parent container (`div class="panel-body"`) and have been unsuccessful.

Is it possible to have the list items expand to the width of the unordered list's parent container?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to maximize the list to consume max space using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629444/how-to-maximize-the-list-to-consume-max-space-using-css)

Comment: @Paulie_D - had a look, could not get that to work.  I'm wondering if this is a bootstrap conflict.

Comment: Check to see if `.central-nav` is at all floated.  If it is, then set `float: none` and then try to apply tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies - a simple oversight - I forgot I wrapped the UL in a Div.

I created a new class as follows:

```
.fill-parent {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I applied that class to the div and the list items expanded to fill the div.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
.central-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
}

.central-nav li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Did not do anything different for me - I'm wondering if this is a bootstrap conflict?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Paulie_D, the tables is a good first method to try.  It is supported in older browsers and, overall, much easier to implement.

If your app will run on a modern browser and you want more control over how list items shrink or grow, their alignment, etc., then you can try flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/J7meX/.

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Styles:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

ul > li {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 33%;
    flex: 1 1 33%;
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following.

```
.central-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.central-nav li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```